# How to achieve CSS-only image glow effect

Tags: html, css, image, css-filters

I have achieved an image glow effect that I like by adding a copy of the image itself in html, as well as blurring and saturating it using CSS filters. However, ideally I would like to achieve the same result without adding the extra html element (i.e. the blurred/saturated image), since it is essentially just a style that I apply to the foreground image. Is this possible? See example of this effect below.

[image]

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

.glow,
.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
 }

.glow {
  filter: blur(30px) saturate(5);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="glow" src="https://ia601706.us.archive.org/8/items/mbid-bbeded36-8d04-4b3b-8b8b-6fa2e4fec570/mbid-bbeded36-8d04-4b3b-8b8b-6fa2e4fec570-27549132408.jpg" />
  <img class="image" src="https://ia601706.us.archive.org/8/items/mbid-bbeded36-8d04-4b3b-8b8b-6fa2e4fec570/mbid-bbeded36-8d04-4b3b-8b8b-6fa2e4fec570-27549132408.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Replace one of them with a pseudo element?

Comment: @CBroe Sounds good, but how?

Comment: Create a pseudo element for the wrapper, and apply `content: url(...)` or `background-image`.

Comment: While the dupe title says 'background image', the method is exactly the same for image elements.

Comment: @TylerH Just because the answer is the same it does not mean that the question is. My question is not asking how to apply blur to a background image, I was specifically asking how to use CSS to remove the need for the extra HTML img tag.

Comment: @FilipÖstermark The fundamental question here, how to apply a blur effect to an image, is the same.

Comment: @TylerH That was not my question at all, in fact in my question I explained that I already did that. What I was asking was: given an image, how do I (1) make a copy of that image, (2) place that image behind the original, before (3) applying the blur effect to that copy, using CSS only. You are suggesting that my question was only step 3 here, which is wrong.

Comment: No, you said you have already done 1, 2, and 3, and you want to achieve the same outcome without having to do 1 and 2. Your specific goal from your question is, and I quote: "However, ideally I would like to achieve the same result without adding the extra html element" This, along with the title of your question, "How to achieve CSS-only image glow effect" are answered in the duplicate. Do not let minor things like implementation details distract you from the actual problem or solution at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to achieve this using a pseudo element ([thank you CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77300014/how-to-achieve-css-only-image-glow-effect/77300891#comment136276671_77300014)!) Here is the solution for now. The extra HTML img tag is no longer required:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}

.image,
.wrapper::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
 }

.wrapper::before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url("https://ia601706.us.archive.org/8/items/mbid-bbeded36-8d04-4b3b-8b8b-6fa2e4fec570/mbid-bbeded36-8d04-4b3b-8b8b-6fa2e4fec570-27549132408.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  filter: blur(30px) saturate(5);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="image" src="https://ia601706.us.archive.org/8/items/mbid-bbeded36-8d04-4b3b-8b8b-6fa2e4fec570/mbid-bbeded36-8d04-4b3b-8b8b-6fa2e4fec570-27549132408.jpg" />
</div>
```